# Labels representing the different sections of a Piechart are overlapping with one another

Tags: javafx, pie-chart

I am developing a *JaxaFX* application that generates reports by taking data from a *MySQL* database. I came across an issue when working with piecharts. Whenever the fetched data is `0`, the label getting displayed for it **overlaps with the other labels** in the piechart making it difficult to read.

[image: Overlapping labels in a piechart]

Relevant bits of Code:

Fetching the Data:

```
Get_data_from_pos_basket_for_reporting getreportPaymentPaidUnpaidNoClass=new Get_data_from_pos_basket_for_reporting();
        getreportPaymentPaidUnpaidNoClass.getreportPaymentPaidUnpaidNo(fromDate, untilDate);
      double amountPaid,amountUnpaid;
      int totalPaid,totalUnpaid;
      amountPaid=getreportPaymentPaidUnpaidNoClass.getAmountPaid();
      amountUnpaid= getreportPaymentPaidUnpaidNoClass.getAmountUnpaid();
      totalPaid=getreportPaymentPaidUnpaidNoClass.getTotalPaid();
      totalUnpaid=getreportPaymentPaidUnpaidNoClass.getTotalUnpaid();
      double totalamountPaidUnpaid=amountPaid+paymentSystem+amountUnpaid;
      double totalNoPaidUnpaid=totalPaid+totalUnpaid;
     // DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

      double percentagePaidAmount=((amountPaid/totalamountPaidUnpaid)*100);
      double percentageUnpaidAmount=((amountUnpaid/totalamountPaidUnpaid)*100);
      double percentagePaidTotal=((totalPaid/totalNoPaidUnpaid)*100);
      double percentageUnpaidTotal=((totalUnpaid/totalNoPaidUnpaid)*100);
```

Setting the Piechart:

```
ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData3 =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new PieChart.Data("Paid\n"+(df.format(percentagePaidAmount))+"%", amountPaid),
                new PieChart.Data("Unpaid\n"+(df.format(percentageUnpaidAmount))+"%", amountUnpaid));

         PieChart chart3 = new PieChart(pieChartData3);



        chart3.getStyleClass().add("chart-legend");       
        chart3.setTitle("Payment Details[Total Amount]");
        VBox vBoxPie3= new VBox();
        vBoxPie3.getChildren().addAll(chart3);
```

Please suggest a solution such that the labels don't overlap with each other.